# Loading UserControl within a Child Window

Tags: silverlight-4.0, user-controls, navigation, silverlight-5.0, childwindow

I have a child window created in silverlight. I need to load a user control within the child window(for a content change in the same child window) on a button click. 
How can i acheive this?

Say for Example: If i have a child window with a Header -> Content -> Button.
I just need to change the content part and the button part on click of the button.
I need to change the buttons also since navigation is not possible using the same button click events.

Is it possible to acheive this in Silverlight 4.0 or 5.0?

Comment: I Know What You Want But For Better Understand Plz Show You Code Or Screen Short

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. Create a canvas to hold the content and on button click, add the user control and add it as a child to the canvas. If you want to change the button, rather than changing the button, in the same button click the button content to a different text.

> private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>
> {
>              SilverlightControl1 control1 = new SilverlightControl1();
>               top.Children.Add(control1);
>   }

Hope this helps.